# Xubuntu doesn't come back after closing lid - Asus ROG STRIX G17

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

After installing xubuntu, and closing the lid, well, the screen freezes into the last thing it was there and the computer becomes unresponsive. Closing it again and opening doesn't change a thing. Had to ctrl+alt+F5 to try and halt the machine. Funny fact, machine also doesn't halt. Gets stuck in the turning off image for xubuntu. Hard to hard reset with the power button.
Works as expected in Windows 10.